# Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets' while running the app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Main error while running the app in Visual Studio Code v1.46.1

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:cleanMergeDebugAssets'.
> Unable to delete directory 'E:\ACNO\Flutter\jots_mobile\build\app\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out'
    Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.
    - E:\ACNO\Flutter\jots_mobile\build\app\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out\flutter_assets\assets
    - E:\ACNO\Flutter\jots_mobile\build\app\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out\flutter_assets\packages\cupertino_icons
    - E:\ACNO\Flutter\jots_mobile\build\app\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out\flutter_assets\packages
    - E:\ACNO\Flutter\jots_mobile\build\app\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out\flutter_assets

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 50s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

This error gets resolved after `flutter clean` but even that shows the following error

Below is the output of `flutter clean`

```
Failed to remove build. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used
Deleting build...                                                   19ms
Failed to remove E:\ACNO\Flutter\jots_mobile\.dart_tool. A program may still be using a file in the directory or the directory itself. To find and stop such a program, see:   
https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used
Deleting .dart_tool...                                              21ms
Deleting Generated.xcconfig...                                       4ms
Deleting flutter_export_environment.sh...
```

Even when I kill the processes which are using *build* and *.dart_tool* folders as mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1333118/cant-delete-empty-folder-because-it-is-used), `flutter clean` will show the same error

So, now I've to manually go to file explorer and delete the *build* & *.dart_tool* folders, which is the main issue here!

**Summary:** Main error while running the app gets resolved after `flutter clean` but even that is showing an error, so now I've to manually go and delete *build* & *.dart_tool* folders!

> Q. How can I resolve these issues?

**Update:** Just noticed that this error occurs when I use "f5" to run my program in VS code and not when I use `flutter run` command in terminal or in Android Studio, but once it has occurred with "f5", it happens with `flutter run` command and Android Studio both. There is something wrong with the extension in VS Code that enables this "f5" shortcut, I guess!

Checkout these GitHub issues • [flutter/flutter](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59975) • [fwcd/vscode-kotlin](https://github.com/fwcd/vscode-kotlin/issues/40)

Comment: Are there any open emulators running the app or is the app still running on a actual device?

Comment: Definitely not, because this error also comes after I restart the device and try running the code!

Comment: Android Studio version 4.0 ? try file -> invalidate caches and restart

Comment: Visual Studio Code --version 1.46.1, I did try my code in Android Studio 4.0 and after invalidating caches & restarting it works fine for just one time... I can't do it every time I want to restart the app!

Comment: i dont have much experience in developing on VScode but on Android Studio, when i  encountered problem with `flutter clean` being unable to delete the build it was because i had not stopped the running app. You are right, every time restarting the IDE is definitely not the solution. This is just trying to guess the cause but In your code do you have any File-read/write/io or any stream operations that might not close immediately even if you stop your app?

Comment: I have initialized "onBackgroundMessage" of FCM on initState() of main.dart and nothing else! BTW, I just checked and this error also happens after I uninstall the app! Currently, this error is only in VS code and the app is running fine on Android Studio, I don't remember last I saw this error on Android Studio!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216402/discussion-between-arshdeep-singh-and-dev-aentgs).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? If so could you post it? It started happening when I upgraded to flutter 1.17.4. I am also using VS code

Comment: If you run the Debug in vs code either on debug mode or profile it will happen 100% of the time

Comment: I tried deleting the build folder / pub cache repair and cleaning the gradle but nothing works.

Comment: @MikeOttink checkout the temporary solutions section just added to the question! Stay updated with the GitHub issue linked in the question.

Comment: So its not only me. I guess its not because flutter 1.17.4. I guess its visual studio code. Because same project works in android studio. If I open visual studio  and android studio at same time and run the project in android studio, this problem occured. If I kill the visual studio code, then the project run properly in android studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was with the Kotlin plugin in VS Code, so removing it should fix our problem!

Now I able to run the project in debug mode. Below is my flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1282, locale en-MY)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.46.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

I reinstall the Kotlin plugin in VS Code, the problem came back. I removed it, the project runs. So I guess its the plugin. The plugin I used and removed is `Kotlin 0.2.17`

Can anyone double-check whether the problem is because of this?

Comment: I was having this problem, and it was the BLOC extension.  Since I wasn't using it, I removed it, and things are working again.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstalling the `Kotlin 0.2.18` extension on VSCode worked for me. I didn't need to delete the build and .dart_tool files mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I solved using "sudo" mode.

```
sudo flutter run
```

I don't have installed Kotlin on VSCode.
I hope to help something

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this, you have to forcefully delete your merged_assets folder and all of its content (i.e 'E:\ACNO\Flutter\jots_mobile\build\app\intermediates\merged_assets\debug\out') since Flutter isn't able to do that for you because one or two programs are using the folders at the background.

To delete the folder forcefully, you can download this exe file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Then, search for 'merged_assets' in the Find tab. Click on the applications using it and kill them (usually dart.exe and cmd.exe).

After this, run flutter clean
Then re-run your app, it should work successfully.

Answer (score 0):

this problem happen because, some other programs used the same files you need to start compile and run your app, one of the program is live Server, make sure to close it, and close any other programs using this app resources 'files' need to compile .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Write in terminal

```
cd android

.\gradlew clean

cd ..
```

and run your progict agin

**Or**

Enter build file and delete app file

If not working

Enter build file and delete everything inside it

**Warning**: prefer do a cut and put it in another place.
Because if not working, Returns it in build file again

Answer (score -1):

I did not had the `VSCODE KOTLIN plug-in`. I just closed **VSCODE**

and from an elivated (admin) CMD-terminal run

```
Flutter run
```

It worked great!!